# hasura unique keys + bool condition

Tags: graphql, hasura

I'm trying to add some custom logic to one of my tables on Hasura Postgre.

| id : PK | user_id : FK | tag_id : FK | is_active : bool |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | xyz | **true** |
| 2 | abc | xyz | false |
| 3 | abc | xyz | false |

Allow **only one row** with same pair of FK's but column **is_active == true**;

Allow **multiple rows** with same pair of FK's but column **is_active == false**;

...

How can I set Hasura up to in case of an insert or update, Hasura would update the old value with **is_active = false** and keep only the new one with **is_active = true** automatically.

Thanks!!!

Comment: In the same GraphQL transaction you can change all the old rows `is_active = false` https://hasura.io/docs/latest/mutations/postgres/update/#update-objects-based-on-their-fields then insert a new row with `is_active = true`  https://hasura.io/docs/latest/mutations/postgres/multiple-mutations/

Comment: There's no way to do this "automatically" through Hasura but you could implement it inside of Postgres with constraints on the table + database triggers

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments. ended up solving with an event trigger to my backend and managing everything from there.